# Do I Really need to install homebrew to install rails and why?

Tags: homebrew

I hope this question is suitable for this forum, I'm still learning what's deemed fit and what isn't. Anyway here is my question,  a lot of places seem to state I need to install homebrew on my mac to install rails, do I really need to and what benefits does it offer to do so and for the development environment?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty bad but I remember when I started programming that I had a similar question, so here we go:

How do you install stuff on your computer? Obviously you use the Mac App Store if you want something from Apple, and if you want to install Chrome just go the Google Chrome website etc.

But when you want some kind of programmer tool, let's say a compiler. How do you install this? Either you go to their website, download a tarball with the source code, compile it from scratch and bind the necessary environment variables. Or you are unlucky and the compiler has a bunch of dependencies so you have to download them first.

Then some geniuses thought that "Oh damn, that's a pain", so instead they created so called *package managers*, so now when I want Rails on my computer, I just installed it through the "gem" ruby package/dependency manager.

So you can install rails through the command "gem" (just google "ruby gem") and you'll see what it is, but I advise you to if you want to have a nice development environment where it's easy to install and uninstall stuff, use brew or macports.

Comment: The *only* part in this that's actually answering the question is the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @cybermonkey True that.